# Jquery dialog not displaying correctly when injected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension and I'm trying to inject Jquery when the user clicks an element on the page. When I try to create a dialog via Jquery by doing:

```
var box = document.createElement('div');
box.id = 'box'
box.title = 'hello'
document.body.appendChild(box);
```

Then

```
$("#box").dialog();
```

Only the close button shows up, along with the text placed next to it. I'm not sure why it's not displaying the full dialog box. The weird thing is that it also varies from site to site. So if I load SO and call the dialog, this appears:

[image: close button screenshot]

But if I load reddit, this appears:

[image: close button screenshot]

It seems that the injected dialog is inheriting properties from the websites that I am injecting it into. I'd like to inject it and have it display the default box if possible. The only time it actually shows the default box is if I inject it into the Jquery index.html sample page that they provide:

[image: website screenshot]

I have jquery-ui.min.css, jquery-ui.min.js, and jquery.min.js all in the extension's directory. It works when I try to load their sample page and inject the dialog there, but not on other websites. If anyone can help fix this, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to completely isolate your styles from the page is using Shadow DOM (which was shipped by Chrome in 2013). You can also use the Dialog element, so Jquery is not even needed.

```js
let shadow
try {
 shadow = document.body.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
 shadow.appendChild(document.createElement("slot"))
} catch(error) {
 shadow = document.body.createShadowRoot()
 shadow.appendChild(document.createElement("content"))
}
let dialog = document.createElement("dialog")
dialog.innerHTML = `
 Test Dialog<br><br>
 <button>Close</button>
`
shadow.appendChild(dialog)
dialog.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
 dialog.remove()
})
dialog.showModal() //or show()
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/09/dialog-element-Modals-made-easy

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to inject any code into a page, you'll have to contend with whatever code is already there. For example, when you inject your own jQuery without taking certain additional steps, you're clobbering the page's existing jQuery (assuming it has one). Doing this could break page functionality.

There currently isn't a way to completely isolate your CSS from the page CSS. The best you can do is create a likely unique id for your dialog's outermost element and alter your injected CSS so that all the rules are prefixed to match this id. You may also need some special reset rules for that id to override whatever the page has going on.

Comment: I see, thanks for the input. So would you suggest not using JQuery at all to create a dialog widget on an existing webpage (that uses JQuery) via a Chrome extension? If so, what do you recommend to achieve this? Thanks again.

Comment: @Zuhayr You can use your own jQuery, you just need to take steps to isolate it. For example, jQuery has [`$.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) that can be used to help with this. For CSS, as I said, there isn't a perfect way of isolating it, but starting all the rules off with a probably unique id should minimize that impact.

Comment: This answer isn't completely correct regarding jQuery. The scripts you inject from an extension have their own scope and can co-exist quite happily with any jQuery already on the web page. You imply that conflict will be the rule whereas in fact it's only rarely you need to consider it. Of course both the extension and the page may conflict if they both try to set the same element of the dom - last will win. Even event handlers work fine without conflict most of the time. There is no need to use $.noConflict() - there is no conflict of the jQuery libraries even with different versions

Comment: @TroyWray Loading jQuery clobbers `window.$` and `window.jQuery`. Pages typically assume that `window.$` is the jQuery they loaded, not some other jQuery. If a browser plugin injects jQuery into a page and doesn't use `$.noConflict(true)` there's a good chance the page's javascript will break. As well, jQuery plugins are typically only available to the jQuery that was associated with `$` at the time the plugin was first initialized. My experience is that there is often conflict between various versions of Jquery especially when considering the 1.x versions.

Comment: yes but this question is about a chrome extension and that doesn't happen because the jquery in the extension, or the extension itself doesn't have access to the same window object as the page jquery and javascript. It has its own window object.